# How would I suppress the print dialog in this example?

Tags: java, printing, dialog

```
private void printCard() {

        PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        printjob.setJobName("Label");

        Printable printable = new Printable() {

                public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {

                        if (pageNum > 0) {
                                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                        }

                        Dimension size = jLayeredPane2.getSize();
                        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                        jLayeredPane2.print(bufferedImage.getGraphics());

                        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
                        g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                        g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);

                        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
                }
        };

        Paper paper = new Paper();
        paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 153, 243);
        paper.setSize(243, 154);

        PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
        format.setPaper(paper);
        format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

        printjob.setPrintable(printable, format);
        if (printjob.printDialog() == false)
                return;

        try {
                printjob.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND." + ex);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in your code, you call `if (printjob.printDialog() == false)`.  This will always try to show the native printer properties dialog.  The `boolean` return value is based on whether the user clicks OK or cancels out of the dialog.  If you want to suppress the dialog, remove that `if` block, as the printing work that you want to perform is done via the `printjob.print()` call.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!  I commented that section out, and I no longer got the print dialog box.  I clicked the print button in my program, and it just printed to the default printer.  Exactly what I wanted.  Thank you so much!