# Silent printing on clients printer for a hospital front desk ADF project

Tags: jasper-reports, oracle-adf, adobe-javascript

I am working on a Hospital front desk ADF project, here I need to generate visit slips these dont require print preview.I want to get to print the slips without any print dialogs nor do I want a popup window. I tried lot of stuff found on the net but nothing solid has come up..
Tried this.print on the Jasper report, tried the same through Java but I am getting dialog. 
I am working on an intranet so the security aspect is out of the discussion so how so I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out a way to do this..

```
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT,
                              "var pp = this.getPrintParams();pp.interactive=pp.constants.interactionLevel.silent;pp.NumCopies=1; this.disclosed= true ;this.print({bUI: false,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true,printParams:pp});");
```

This adds pdf javascript to the generated pdf..
Once the pdf is displayed on the popup page it performs the silent print.. Hope this helps someone in the future..

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion rather than an answer, but I can't write comments before I get 50 points of reputation - maybe one of these will help:

1. [Printing an html file using java without showing print dialog to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695900/printing-an-html-file-using-java-without-showing-print-dialog-to-the-user)
2. [How would I suppress the print dialog in this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106379/how-would-i-suppress-the-print-dialog-in-this-example)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform the silent print, I used a popup window to call a servlet which generated the required visit slip and displayd the same on the pop window. For the silent print I used

```
                exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print({bUI: false,bSilent: false,bShrinkToFit: true,printParams:this.getPrintParams().constants.interactionLevel.silent});this.close();");
```

I had to make a couple of changes to IE, I added my url to the trusted site option in IE. I enabled js in acrobat and also pointed acrobat to the trusted sites in IE. This resolved silent print but am stuck with another issue..

I am not being able to close the window once print is done.. I tried this..

```
            "var win = window.open('PrintPopUp.jsf','_blank',\"height=300,width=200,scrollbars=no," +
        "status=no, resizable=no, screenx=0, screeny=0\");win.onclick=function(){setTimeout(function(){win.close();\n},9000);}
```

But its not working in IE 11.. any suggestions?